# 17539 decimal to binary not getting the same result

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary

I'm trying to convert 17539 to binary. My math says its 110000010010001, but online calculators like [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html) and [this](http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/converters/hex-to-bin-to-dec.php) say it equals to 100010010000011. Who is making something wrong.

Comment: You wrote it little-endian, and the online calculators big-endian.

Comment: I get $\mathtt{100010010000011}$ too; so your math is wrong. The first remainder you get is the rightmost digit, not the leftmost one. In order to do it right, think that the first remainder can be $0$, so it can't be the leftmost digit unless the given number is zero.

Comment: I don't understand you! @DanielFischer

Comment: $17539 = 2^{14} + 2^{10} + 2^{7} + 2^1 + 2^0$. You write the bit for $2^0$ in the first (leftmost) place and the bit for $2^{14}$ in the last (rightmost). The calculators wrote it the other way round.

Comment: @Enve: You're writing your result backwards, with the ones column at the left instead of at the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
&&17539=2\cdot8769+1\\
&&8769=2\cdot4384+1\\
&&4384=2\cdot2192+0\\
&&2192=2\cdot1096+0\\
&&1096=2\cdot548+0\\
&&548=2\cdot274+0\\
&&274=2\cdot137+0\\
&&137=2\cdot68+1\\
&&68=2\cdot34+0\\
&&34=2\cdot17+0\\
&&17=2\cdot8+1\\
&&8=2\cdot4+0\\
&&4=2\cdot2+0\\
&&2=2\cdot1+0\\
&&1=2\cdot0+1
\end{align}

The binary representation is $\mathtt{100010010000011}$, because the first remainder you get represents the multiplier of $2^0$, just like $9$ in $17539$ is the remainder of the first division by $10$.

How do you remember? Think doing this with $2$:
\begin{align}
&&2=2\cdot1+0\\
&&1=2\cdot0+1
\end{align}
and it would be of course wrong to write $\mathtt{01}$ for the binary representation, wouldn't it?

Comment: $274 = 2\cdot 137 + 0$, not $+ 1$. And $68 = 2\cdot 34 + 0$, not $39$ (that's correct on the next line).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks; I made some mistakes during the computation and I didn't correct all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your value is the calculator value written in reverse order.  You are doing the calculation correctly, but not recognizing that the first remainder is the one's bit, not the high order bit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
17539 &= \color{red}1\cdot 2^{14}+ \color{red}0\cdot2^{13} + \color{red}0\cdot2^{12} +\color{red}0\cdot2^{11}+ \color{red}1\cdot 2^{10} \\ &+ \color{red}0\cdot2^{9} + \color{red}0\cdot2^{8} + \color{red}1\cdot 2^7 + \color{red}0\cdot2^{6} + \color{red}0\cdot2^{5} \\&+ \color{red}0\cdot2^{4} +\color{red}0\cdot2^{3} +\color{red}0\cdot2^{2} +\color{red}1\cdot 2^1 + \color{red}1\cdot 2^0.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This python program converts from decimal to base 2.

```
 def convert(x):
        if x == 0 or x == 1:
            return str(x)
        return convert(x//2) + str(x%2)

    print(convert(17539))
```

Just change the number to what you want.  This produces a character string with
the desired binary expansion.  It works by "nibbling at the little end."  It mechanizes egreg's nice calculation.